# Parse object saves data but can't access it until I quit/relogin iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm using Parse for my backend on an iOS app.  As part of the app, users are able to go to a map, pull up an address, outline a shape by selecting coordinates, and then name the property.  The VC in which you set the name is the one right after the one where you set the outline.  When I set the name, it properly shows up in the data console on Parse right away, but when I access the name elsewhere, it shows up blank.  All other data associated with the property appears fine.  When I reset the app and sign back in, the property name appears again.  I can't figure out why it doesn't show up in the first place.  I first save all of the data about the property after you outline it like so:

```
    [Lawn setObject:paths forKey:@"paths"];
    [Lawn setObject:self.addressLabel.text forKey:@"address"];
    [Lawn setObject:self.SQFT.text forKey:@"sizeOfLawn"];
    [Lawn setObject:user forKey:@"user"];
    [Lawn setObject:@"" forKey:@"propertyName"];
    [Lawn setObject:[PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:self.serviceAreaMapView.camera.target.latitude longitude:self.serviceAreaMapView.camera.target.longitude] forKey:@"location"];
    [Lawn save];
    [user addObject:Lawn forKey:@"Lawns"];
    NSLog(@"Added lawn with ID %@ to user with ID %@", [Lawn objectId], [user objectId]);
    [user save];
```

That works fine, and all of my data shows up in my data browser as I transition to the next VC.  On the next view controller, I there is a textField that the user can enter a name for the property in.  When they hit save, I save the data like so:

```
    NSLog(@"(property details) Lawn objectID = %@", [Lawn objectId]);
[Lawn fetchIfNeeded];
[Lawn setObject:self.propertyNameTextField.text forKey:@"propertyName"];
[Lawn save];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"propertyDetailsNext" sender:self];
```

My output has shown that I'm saving to the correct lawn, and this is also reflected in the data console.  As I go to the next screen, the lawn is already updated with its property name.

A few VCs later, I have a view controller that displays the property again.  Using this code:

```
_address.text = [Lawn valueForKey:@"address"];
self.navigationItem.title = [Lawn valueForKey:@"propertyName"];
```

I set a label with the address I stored in the VC where I outlined the lawn, and I set the title on the nav bar to be the name of the property I saved. However, the name shows up blank.  All other information, including a correct mapping of a shape based on the coordinates saved with the lawn show up fine, it's just that propertyName string that does not.  It is a string in the Parse data console, as is the address.  I don't understand why one shows up fine but the other doesn't.

There are other places throughout my app that attempt to use the property name, and it shows up blank as well.  The other data is pulled fine.

This all continues until I reset the app and sign in again.  The propertyName displays fine everywhere.

Any tips on what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: When you are accessing it on the other views, are you fetching those from Parse or are you passing a reference to object you created before ?

Comment: I pass the id like this in prepareForSegue to a NSString, then perform a query on the class Lawn and look for the objectId. It gives me the correct Lawn, as it properly saves the data in the data console.  I'm trying the answer below, I'll let you guys know if it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are using `save` and the immediately performing a segue. I don't think the save can work that fast.

If you use `[saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {}];` block method and put your segue in side that block it should work.

Like so

```
[saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
         if (succeeded) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"propertyDetailsNext" sender:self];
         } else {
            //Log your error here
         }
}];
```

Comment: Don't forget to check if (succeeded) { }

Comment: I set my saves to use this format in both of my view controllers, and I'm still getting the same problem.  I'm also calling [Lawn fetchIfNeeded] before accessing anything inside the lawn.  Should I be using a fetchInBackground, too?

Comment: In your `prepareForSegue` method are you transferring your lawn object to the next VC?

Comment: Im sending the [Lawn objectId] as an NSString, then doing a query on object with class type "Lawn", then getting the objectWIthId: with the NSString I used.  It is definitely pulling the correct Lawn because of the updates in the data console.  Are you able to send the whole object?  I was under the impression objective c could only handle passing simpler objects from one VC to another.  I had problems trying to pass whole labels when I first started.

Comment: Okay well where you have methods like `[save]` and `fetchinbackground` do them in them in them in the background with those block methods. And where you setting values for things in your view controller, put that inside the block.

Comment: fetchInBackground did it! Thanks.  I marked you as correct, but you may want to add something about making sure to use fetchInBackground as well to your answer for posterity.